# How do i Check object.property is defined in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there any equivalent function in angular 2 as `angular.isDefined` as in angular 1

Checked The safe navigation operator `?.` which only supports in tempalte

Answer (score 7):

Typescript does NOT have a function to check if a variable is defined, neither does Angular2.

Using a juggling-check, you can test both null and undefined in one hit:

```
if (object.property == null) {
```

If you use a strict-check, it will only be true for values set to null and won't evaluate as true for undefined variables:

```
if (object.property === null) {
```

Answer (score 1):

no

angular2 uses proper JavaScript. it moves away from angular specific language. that is one of its goals.

just do ..

```
if (something == null) { // the only exception where double equals is OK - checks for undefined or null
    ...
}
```

Typescript does have a !. operator which might be worth looking at, not exactly sure how it works but i think it is similar to ?.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `undefined`

```
function getSchool(name: string, address?: string, pinCode?: string): string {
            if (address == undefined) {
                console.log('address not defined');
            }
            if (pinCode == undefined) {
                console.log('pincode not defined');
            }
}
```